# Video.js video fill div

Tags: javascript, css, video.js

Is it possible to tell video.js to fill a div with the video? In my experimenting it only seems possible to set the dimensions (either with `size()` or `width()` and `height()`).

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution done entirely in HTML and CSS:

http://www.hexagonwebworks.com/2012/responsive-videos-updated/

Comment: Could you paste a short version or fiddle as an answer? A link to a blog isn't advisable as blogs often expire or go down.